# How to generate while loop using the LLVM C++ api

Tags: c++, llvm-ir

How do I generate a while loop using the llvm c++ api. I would like to understand how the branching and phi instructions work together

Comment: You can make a while loop just using branches without a phi instruction.

Comment: To add to @TobiasWilfert point, you can create any kind of program without using `phi instructions`. To be able to see `phi instructions` in your `LLVM IR` code you would have to run a `mem2reg pass` over it.

Comment: @TobiasWilfert could you provide an example of generating a while loop without phi instructions?

Comment: Ok I finally generated the loop successfully